# How should I associate two objects if I only want to create join table records?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities - products and gift boxes. A box can contain 7 items. The same product might be added to many boxes . the entities were generated from existing tables (including the join table products_to_boxes).

I've created a unidirectional ManyToMany association between boxes and products using the join table. When creating a new box, I want to add existing products, not create new product records. In other words, I want to create 7 new join table records and 1 box record when I create a box, not 8 new item records...

Is this a known kind of object graph, does it have a name and is a ManytoMany association appropriate?

Comment: sounds exactly like a many to many to me

Comment: @DerickF thanks. The slight nuance as I see it is that when creating a new box, I want to add existing products to it rather then create new product records. I'm trying to understand if that is a particular kind of many to many or whether that can be specified in Doctrine in some way

Comment: you can set a cascade option, e.g. cascade={"detach"}
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations